# How do I label the terminal nodes of a cut dendrogram?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, dendextend

I used the following code to cut the dendrogram at a particular height.The problem I'm having is that when I cut a dendrogram, I can't figure out how to add labels to the nodes.How can I cut a dendrogram with labels using R program?

```
library(Heatplus)
cc=as.dendrogram(hclust(as.dist(mat),method="single"))
cutplot.dendrogram(cc,h=20)
```

Comment: What is a dendogram, and what language is this?

Comment: @john this is R language.I am tying to do hierarcial clustering using R.

Comment: Ok, and what is a dendogram? At least say what area of knowledge defines it. Statistics? Physics?

Comment: @ John A dendrogram (from Greek dendron "tree", -gramma "drawing") is a tree diagram frequently used to illustrate the arrangement of the clusters produced by hierarchical clustering. Dendrograms are often used in computational biology to illustrate the clustering of genes or samples.

Comment: The updated title better describes the question; you don't want to cut the dendrogram but label the terminal nodes of the cut dendrogram.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank you for applying the [tag:r]-tag

Answer (score 6):

After a fair amount of digging into the help documentation for `?dendrogram`, I stumbled on the `dendrapply` function that contains an example to do something very similar.  Here is your solution, based on a modification of the example in `?dendrapply`:

Create dendrogram and cut at height `h=20`:

```
dhc <- as.dendrogram(hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave"))
chc <- cut(dhc, h=20)$upper
```

Define a vector with the newLabels, and a function `newLab` that modifies an individual node label. Then pass this to `dendrapply`:

```
newLabels <- paste("Custom", 1:22, sep="_")

local({
      newLab <<- function(n) {
        if(is.leaf(n)) {
          a <- attributes(n)
          i <<- i+1
          attr(n, "label") <- newLabels[i]
        }
        n
      }
      i <- 0
    })

nhc <- dendrapply(chc, newLab)
labels(nhc)
 [1] "Custom_1"  "Custom_2"  "Custom_3"  "Custom_4"  "Custom_5"  "Custom_6" 
 [7] "Custom_7"  "Custom_8"  "Custom_9"  "Custom_10" "Custom_11" "Custom_12"
[13] "Custom_13" "Custom_14" "Custom_15" "Custom_16" "Custom_17" "Custom_18"
[19] "Custom_19" "Custom_20" "Custom_21" "Custom_22"

plot(nhc)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified solution for what Andrie wrote, but using a new package called "[dendextend](https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend)", built exactly for this sort of thing.

You can see many examples in the presentations and vignettes of the package, in the "usage" section in the following URL: https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend

Here is the solution for this question:

```
# define dendrogram object to play with:
dhc <- as.dendrogram(hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave"))
chc <- cut(dhc, h=20)$upper
# loading the package
require(dendextend)# let's add some color:
# change labels with a simple assignment:
labels(chc) <- paste("Custom", 1:22, sep="_")
plot(chc)
```

For installing the package (since I have yet to upload it to CRAN), use:

```
####################
## installing dendextend for the first time:

if (!require('installr')) install.packages('installr'); require('installr')
## install.Rtools() # run this if you are using Windows and don't have Rtools
require2(devtools)
install_github('dendextend', 'talgalili')
require2(Rcpp)
install_github('dendextendRcpp', 'talgalili')
```

Best,
Tal

Answer (score -1):

```
cc$labels
```

This is a vector of all the elements in the dendogram.

```
cc$labels <- myVector
```

You can add in your own vector to change the labels