# Add non-numeric labels to dendrogram from agnes

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to use the cluster routine agnes in R to perform UPGMA and generate a dendrogram with nodes labeled with text values that equal study sites names (not numbers).  I am lousy with R but got the dist matrix and analyses to run but am having trouble plotting.  I followed instructions at the link below but am getting an error message.

[How do I label the terminal nodes of a cut dendrogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199571/how-do-i-label-the-terminal-nodes-of-a-cut-dendrogram)

```
#Simpson dissim 
library(betapart)
dist.sim<-beta.pair(Data, index.family="sor")
class(dist.sim)
betasim.sim<-dist.sim[["beta.sim"]]
class(betasim.sim)

UPGMA.orig<-agnes(betasim.sim)

labels = read.csv("labels.csv", header = T)
labels = labels$label
as.vector(labels)

local({
  newLab <<- function(n) {
    if(is.leaf(n)) {
      a <- attributes(n)
      i <<- i+1
      attr(n, "label") <- labels[i]
    }
    n
  }
  i <- 0
})

 UPGMA.orig<- dendrapply(dagn , newLab)
 labels(UPGMA.orig)
```

Error in print.factor(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_ : 
  replacement has length zero

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
dagn  <- as.dendrogram(as.hclust(UPGMA.orig))
dagn2 <- as.dendrogram(as.hclust(UPGMA.orig), hang = 0.2)
op <- par(mar = par("mar") + c(0,0,0,4)) # more space to the right
plot(dagn2, horiz = TRUE)
plot(dagn, horiz = TRUE, center = TRUE,
 nodePar = list(lab.cex = 0.6, lab.col = "black", pch = NA, labels=labels),
 main = paste("Sky Island Birds"), xlab = "Dissimilarity (ßsim)" ,  xlim=c(0.4, 0))
par(op)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to add text labels?  I see nothing in the agnes object and can add labels through plot().